# useEffect doesn't work when I redirect back to my site from another site

Tags: reactjs

I faced an interesting thing.
Аccording to a logic on my site I redirect to my site page back after I enter a code on another site. There is useEffect at the root of my app where the connection to sockets occurs.
UseEffect does not work and sockets are not connected after a redirect from another site. What can I do to make useEffect work? Or what can I do else in this situation?

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect') 
        webSocket.current = new WebSocket(URL_WEB_SOCKET);
        webSocket.current.onopen = () => {
            console.log('opened')
        };

        return () => {
            if (webSocket.current) {
                webSocket.current.close();
            }
        };
    }, [])
```

Comment: What do you use for redirecting? It should work if nothing is wrong. `useEffect` on your code    only works when site rendered for the first time. So you should check that.

Comment: "UseEffect does not work" please elaborate. It is not being triggered at all after redirect or it is being triggered but failing to establish connection ?

Comment: Thank you for help! I solved problem by checking the url for redirect. After redirect I get to another host. They look pretty similar (like ejdh2837.com and  ejdh2737.com)

Comment: I am under the impression that WebSocket connections are subject to the same-origin policy. But perhaps your specific usecase covers it. Good to know it's solved!